# AngularJS Directives: Take a HTML attribute as a string, used as a dictionary key

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'd like to make an equation tag, and use a label attribute to look up which equation to use. Towards that end I have the following app:

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('mathDocument', []);

    app.directive('equation', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                label: '@label'}, 
            templateUrl: 'eqnElement.html',
        };
    });

    app.controller("DocumentController", function(){
        this.equations = {
                "mainresult": { labeled: true,
                                label: 'mainresult',
                                body: 'e^{i\\pi} = -1',
                              }
        };
    });
})();
```

And a template in eqnElement.html:

```
<body ng-controller="DocumentController as doc">
    <div>
        {{ doc.equations[label].body }}
    </div>
</body>
```

But, when I try to use the equation tag,

```
<equation label="mainresult"></equation>
```

I end up not getting anything. If I instead used `{{ label }}`, I'd end up seeing `mainresult` as the output of the template.

From what I've read, the usage of an isolate scope plays badly with controllers and might be the problem, but I'm having a hard time getting my debugger to show me anything helpful regarding that. Is there a way to make this work, or should I think about designing this differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass in the `equations` to the directives scope as well, you can have access to them:

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('mathDocument', []);

    app.directive('equation', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                label: '@label',
                equations: '='
            }, 
            templateUrl: 'eqnElement.html',
        };
    });

    app.controller("DocumentController", function($scope){
        $scope.equations = {
                "mainresult": { labeled: true,
                                label: 'mainresult',
                                body: 'e^{i\\pi} = -1',
                              }
        };
    });
})();
```

When calling the directive:

```
<equation equations="equations" label="mainresult"></equation>
```

And eqnEquation.html:

```
<div>
    {{ equations[label].body }}
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your example, but it didn't work? I modified all three files correctly I believe.

Comment: I assume you have your `ng-app` attribute on the `html` or `body` tag, and you're calling `app.run()` somewhere on the page?

Comment: I have that attribute on the `html` tag, yes. I wasn't calling `app.run()` but I added a script to do so and still no dice. I'm using angular 1.3.9 and Python's simple web server to test this, would those cause any problems?

Comment: @TedDokos Here is a plunker of the working app: http://plnkr.co/rDwGvt7bedLjgAs6NFHr

Comment: It looks like you've hard-coded the string `'mainresult'` into the template. I wanted that to be the label attribute a la: `template: {{ equations[label].body }}` and that doesn't work if I change it in the plunker.

Comment: Yes, you are right, at some point I accidentally camel-cased my label attribute and that's what was causing the failure. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

You never bound doc to the scope in your directive. Inject the equations service and call it doc in the scope, then it will work.

Comment: I'm a little confused how I'd do that. Could you elaborate?